# How to interpret year dummies and individual effects in fixed effects one-way model?

Tags: r, time, fixed, effects, plm

I am working on my research trying to investigate whether investors are willing to accept a lower yield for holding bonds with environmental benefits in comparison to conventional bonds. I created 101 matched pairs of bonds with the same characteristics apart from the fact that one is a "green" bond financing environmental projects and the other one a standard bond. In my analysis, I observe the difference in their ask yields - for each bond couple I have daily data on the difference in their ask yield from the bond origination until January 2020. Having this unbalanced 44,863 bond-day panel, I am now running a fixed-effects unbalanced panel regression in R using the plm package:

```
model_fe = plm(yield_diff ~ Bid_ask, data  = mydata.set, model = "within")
```

I am primarirly interested in the unobserved individual fixed effects, captured by the intercepts.

However, I would also wish to investigate the time effects and see whether the dependent variable (the difference in the yield, i.e. the price) changes over years. However, using two-way fixed effects model adds day effects which are jointly not significant. Therefore, I want to add year dummies to see if the yield difference between environmental and conventional bonds has changed in time.

Considering my data span from 2014 - 2020, I estimate the following equation, leaving out a dummy variable for 2014 to prevent multicollienarity problem:

```
model_YearDummies = plm(yield_diff ~ bid_ask + 2015 + 2016 + 2017 + 2017 + 2018 + 2019 + 2020, data  = mydata.set_YearDummies, model = "within")
```

4 out of the 6 year dummies are statistically significant. However, now also the individual fixed effects changed significantly and became larger. Can it be that the intercepts now somehow include also the effect of the year 2014? I would think in order to distinguish the year effects from the individual effects, I need to include year dummies for each one of year (i.e. include dummy for 2014 as well) but R doesn't allow me to do that...

What is the right approach here? Shall I include the year dummies and interpret their coefficients but for the individual effects report results of the initial estimation with no time effects?

What about splitting the dataset into subsamples according to the years, estimating the original equation for each subsample and examine the difference in the average of the individual effects?

Comment: My best advice is to read the vignette of the package **plm** which you can find [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/vignettes/plmPackage.html). You can also have a look at the book by Wooldridge [here](https://economics.ut.ac.ir/documents/3030266/14100645/Jeffrey_M._Wooldridge_Introductory_Econometrics_A_Modern_Approach__2012.pdf)

Comment: Does your formula actually work? If your data frame has a variable `year`, then (at least with most standard models) the formula `yield_diff ~ bid_ask + as.factor(year)` will tell R to treat year as a factor, and it will automatically generate the dummy variables you want.  It won't show a coefficient for 2014 because otherwise the model wouldn't be identifiable (I guess you might call that extreme multicollinearity, but it really isn't the problem - the model matrix is singular).